# How do I deal with unfulfilled maven properties in my dev environment

Tags: maven, development-environment

We are using a maven plugin that sets version properties. These properties are used in the POM files to create the file name of the War, EJB and EAR files - and used by Jenkins.

My problem is that when I import a maven project or re-import IntelliJ uses theses file names to generate artifacts, but the artifact names become weird because the properties are not generated on import (the plugin is not run).

The outermost / top pom has these props:
${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}

iqe-ws${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}

the EAR Pom file has this prop:
iqe-${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}

So the ear artifact file ends up with looking like:
iqe-${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.ear

If I hard code the Props - say 2 and 1  the it becomes 
iqe-2.1.ear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways of dealing with this.

The best is to use profiles. Put the original version of the properties are in a profile that is used on the CI box, and a set with specific values are held in a profile that is used in your local environment. Profiles are activated on the CI box using the `-P profile-name` switch, and in IntelliJ by selecting the appropriate profile in the maven project's window. It may even be possible to activate the correct profile automatically depending on the existence of an environment property or OS.

Alternatively, you could just override the properties using a local settings.xml file, but this would be specific to you and harder to distribute to the team and to future developers, so it's not a great solution.

Here's a [link to the maven profiles documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).